# Проверка значения аргумента constexpr функции

Tags: c++

Есть класс и перегрузка оператора []

```
template <class T, size_t N>
class Vect
{
public:
typedef unsigned int size_type;

T coord[N] = {};

constexpr T& operator [] (size_type index)
    {
            return coord[index];
    }
}
```

Возможно каким то образом в compile-time проверить значение аргумента index? (index >= 0 && index < N)

Comment: конкретно  для  operator []  логичнее возвращать не константу, дабы иметь возможность изменить значение по данному индексу.  Индекс лучше проверять во время выполнения. Другое дело, если проверяет другой метод

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы иметь возможность проверять какое-то значение во время компиляции, это значение должно использоваться в подходящем для этого контексте. Аргумент функции к такому контексту не относится. А вот если реализовать шаблонную функцию с non-type параметром, то это уже удастся сделать. Правда синтаксис уже будет иной:

```
#include <cstdlib>

template <class T, size_t N>
class Vect
{
public:
typedef unsigned int size_type;

T coord[N] = {};

template <size_type I>
constexpr T& get() 
{
    static_assert(I < N);       
    return coord[I];
}
};

int main() {

    Vect<int, 10> v;

    v.get<9>();   // OK
    v.get<10>();  // Ошибка компиляции  
}
```

Подобный функционал уже имеется в стандартной библиотеке при использовании `std::get` на `std::array`.